# ArcPy Label Class object returning unexpected value for expression property?

Tags: arcpy, labeling

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "TestFile_LineToPoints13_Prod"):
    if lyr.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
        for lblclass in lyr.labelClasses:            
            lblclass.expression = " [OBJECTID]"
            if lblClass.showClassLabels:
                    print "    Class Name:  " + lblClass.className
                    print "    Expression:  " + lblClass.expression
mxd.save()
del mxd
```

Prints:

> Class Name:  Default
>
> Expression:  [Shape_Length]

The label for that layer is even set at ObjectID and is currently showing the labels... Why does it keep responding Shape_Length?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code instead which I think will work because I tested it.

I suspect:

```
lblclass.expression = " [OBJECTID]"
```

should be:

```
lblclass.expression = "[OBJECTID]"
```

I also changed `lblclass` to lblClass in two places and used some more `print` statements while I was debugging.

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "TestFile_LineToPoints13_Prod"):
    print lyr.name
    if lyr.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
        print lyr.name + " supports label classes"
        for lblClass in lyr.labelClasses:
            print lblClass.className
            lblClass.expression = "[OBJECTID]"
            if lblClass.showClassLabels:
                    print "    Class Name:  " + lblClass.className
                    print "    Expression:  " + lblClass.expression
mxd.save()
del mxd
```

Comment: When I added [0] I get a runtime error on line 3. Basically says AttributeError: Layerobject: Get attribute layers does not exist

Comment: @Numus I've added some tested code that I think should work better - adding `[0]` was unnecessary although I am surprised it threw that error.

Comment: that seemed to work... It was probably the lower case class that was messing it up.

Now I need to test it when I integrate it with my script but that won't be until tomorrow.